# Strategy for selectively enabling features in a mobile application

Tags: android, ios, testing

Assuming an application that has no login, how can one go about allowing some of its user access to activate 'hidden' features.

An example I recently came across is the need for some users to see a different version of the data feed the app is using (official feed vs editor feed which is being modified/approved)

In android, I assume that we could just point those user to downloading a specific file and test for that file presence in the app but I dont believe this approach can be used on iOS (sandbox).

The approaches I came up with:

- Hide an activator in the UI: specific touches/gestures, invisible button and the like
- Make the user visit a site which sets a cookie when on a specific page and test for that cookie's value in the app to enable features.

Did someone came up with a more elegant solution?

Comment: What about two or more app`s version using flavors with just small changes? Like a white label

Comment: @LucasPaolillo it's an idea, having already managed multiple active versions already, I am not a big fan tough. It certainly is the cheapest to implement I would guess

Comment: Yes... If you will just have few versions, flavors are a good solution, otherwise, its hard to manage...

Comment: An app can write to its own sandbox, so if an app can download something, it can store it in its sandbox.

Comment: By the iOS sandbox limitation, I meant that I could send a link by mail so that chosen android users download a file in their sdcard. In the app I would check for the file presence to unlock the feature. In iOS, you would have to be in-app to download in the app sandbox which dont help much or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS you can [register an association between your app and a file extension](https://stevenpsmith.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/using-custom-file-types-to-import-data-into-your-ios-apps/). Then if you send an iOS user an email containing an attachment with this file extension, iOS will open your app and you'll have access to the file. You could save to the sandbox from there.

Answer (score 3):

You can try any AB testing tool like [Optimizely](https://www.optimizely.com) , [Apptimize](http://apptimize.com/), [Taplytics](https://taplytics.com) or [MixPanel](https://mixpanel.com)

They will help you to try new features by enabling them to only a group of users. Also you can set goals to each variant so you can compare how they perform.

[image: Optimizely: Audience example]

Answer (score 1):

Create a [settings bundle](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app/). Then the user can just go into the Settings app to switch your 'hidden' behaviour on and off.

Comment: Too permissive for my specific use case but elegant and easy to implement. I completely overlooked settings, thanks!

Comment: So tell me more about your specific use case. How do you want a user to arrange access to the hidden features? By paying you something? Ringing you up with a compliment? Who are the "some users" who are more equal than others?

Comment: Sounds like you should be doing in-app purchases.

Comment: 2nd paragraph: official feed vs editor feed which is being modified/approved is an example. In my case the editorial feed contains information which should not be shown to the general public until released

Comment: basically the editorial feed is used to test that the content renders well and nothing got forgotten before being approved. It is often filled with various items days before a public event which marks the release

Comment: So you should let regular users in without a login, but when an editor wants to edit something they have to login.

Comment: I agree, but since I dont have a login flow for normal users, I was thinking of "Hide an activator in the UI: specific touches/gestures, invisible button and the like" that could trigger a login form... now that I think of it tough I could trigger a login form if enabled from settings too :P

Answer (score 0):

Just Like In-app purchases, when user completes a purchase some of the features in application gets unlocked.

I think best approach would be to have data maintained on your server end, the users vs features and in splash screen you get the response from server which of the application's feature are enabled for this user using a service call.

Obviously you must be needing some kind of business logic to implement the flow of enabled features in the application and that is totally up to you whether you use SharedPreferences of keep the information in txt or some other files.

Comment: I do not see how could it be implemented this way without user login/credentials eliminating 'normal' users? In-App purchase the credentials are not managed by you but it becomes the same since apple hits your service once the purchase is validated

Comment: Well if you don't have login credentials then you should have something else to identify the users. On what basis do you need to differentiate the features for specific users?

Comment: I assume through an action that is not easy to guess. I put an example of a situation in the question. Maybe a better example would be like a newspaper app where the editor want to validate the presentation of the content they input in a CMS before exposing its users